# Get the whole object out of its attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, html5-audio, addeventlistener

I have this array of objects:

```
var spot1 = { audio: new Audio("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3c/Postalveolar_click.ogg"),name: "spot1" }
var spot2 = { audio: new Audio("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0a/Open_back_rounded_vowel.ogg"),name: "spot2" }

var allSpots = [spot1, spot2];
```

spot1 and spot2 are objects with an audio object attribute and a name attribute.
I added a onended event listener to them:

```
spot1.audio.onended = function() {
  console.log("hfg");
   $("[spot=" + spot1.name + "]").removeClass('fa-pause');
   $("[spot=" + spot1.name + "]").addClass('fa-play');
};

spot2.audio.onended = function() {
  console.log("hfg");
   $("[spot=" + spot2.name + "]").removeClass('fa-pause');
   $("[spot=" + spot2.name + "]").addClass('fa-play');
};
```

What I'm trying to do is iterate through the "allSpots" array and add an event listener to each one of the audio object attribute of each one of the spot objects. Then I need to change the properties of an HTML element according to which of the spot has ended. This should look somewhat like this:

```
for(var i=0; i< allSpots.length; i++) {
  allSpots[i].audio.onended = function(){
   $("[data-spot=" + allSpots[i].name + "]").removeClass('fa-pause');
   $("[data-spot=" + allSpots[i].name + "]").addClass('fa-play');
  }
}
```

The HTML elements looks like this:

```
<a class="play-pause-button fa fa-play" data-spot="spot1"></a>
<a class="play-pause-button fa fa-play" data-spot="spot2"></a>
```

My problem is that when iterating through the array allSpots[i] inside the eventListener always becomes the object spot2, while I need spot1 or spot2 depending on which audio has ended.

Here is the codepen: https://codepen.io/BrunoKreiner/pen/qpGRoL

Comment: That's about as pretty as it gets. Is there a specific issue you have with it? One thing to note is that `spot` is a non-standard attribute. I'd suggest using `data-spot` instead.

Comment: yeah i didnt really ask the question, but my code doesn't work. I edited my post. The problem is in the last paragraph. I could just write it out and create 2 eventListeners on both objects (spot1 and spot2) so that i know which spot object to use. #Changed "spot" to "data-spot"

Comment: Can you change this `var i = 0` to `let i = 0`